# Kong basic auth plugin not working in minikube

Tags: minikube, kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I am trying to configure kong's basic-auth plugin for a service running in minikube, following [this](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/guides/allowing-multiple-authentication-methods/).

Configs are as:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kong-routing
  annotations:
    konghq.com/strip-path: 'true'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
    konghq.com/plugins: awesome-basic-auth  
spec:
  ingressClassName: kong
  rules:
  - host: kong.experiment
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /my-api
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: myservice
            port:
              number: 30050
---
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: awesome-basic-auth
config:
  anonymous: anonymous
  hide_credentials: true
plugin: basic-auth
---
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongConsumer
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
  name: testuser
credentials:
  - my-basic-auth
username: testuser
```

Secret:

```
kubectl create secret generic my-basic-auth --from-literal=kongCredType=basic-auth --from-literal=username=testuser --from-literal=password=testpw
```

I have also configured anonymus user and request termination plugin for it, as explained in the link.

Based on [this documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/addons/kong-ingress/), I have also executed:

```
minikube addons enable kong
```

But I don't see any impact of all this.  I can still access end points with Basic Auth in postman, no matter if user credentials are absent or wrongly set in request headers.

What am I missing in the whole picture?